# google chrome popup/push notification when google sheet cell value changes

Tags: google-chrome, google-sheets, notifications, google-chrome-devtools

Hi I have a shared google sheet where everyone will put values. **I need some mechanism that will trigger a popup notification in chrome even if the sheet is not open**. This will trigger when a particular cell/column/row value changes.

i searched the web vigorously for some ad dons or script but couldn't find one. everyone i found will send email but i don't need 100, 1000 email. i need just popup/push notification.

i have no background in coding i'm trying to teach myself step by step so elaborated answer will be very appreciated.

Comment: You can easily track changes to the spreadsheet via Apps Script triggers. The problem is on the notification part. Does the notification has to be specifically push notifications to Chrome? Maybe you could send an email, and configure the email settings so that [it triggers a notification](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1075549) and, if the mail comes from the Apps Script trigger, remove it automatically.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i thought of that but i 100s of 1000 of mail will be a problem though you suggest to automatically remove the mail as well. that is neat. but one more problem is that if i use this push notification via mail then everyone who should be notified have to configure their mail to notification as well.

Answer (score 0):

so after a lot of searching i found a way, though not working 100% correctly all the time but it can , have to just polish some values and conditions.

there is a service called [www.integromat.com](https://www.integromat.com/) they have a great way to almost integrate anything with anything. and this solved the problem.but they are expensive.

they has add on for sheet as well as chrome which can talk to each other with super easy dashboard.

though this is a third party dependent solution i would like to know if it is possible within gsuit and or sheet.